# I can't put the values of my Array List inside my jsonObjectReturn

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to put values from my array list to my jsonObjectReturn but I can't put it. It just returns 0 value. Here's my code snippet:

```
List<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();

        jsonObjectReturn =  JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

        for (int i = 4; i <= 27; i++) {
            values.add(callableStatement.getString(i));
            ..//I'm getting the values here..

        }

        System.out.println("The list: " + values.toString());
```

the output of this is **The list: [118708139, I, , LABRAMONTE, JESUS, CALUMPIANO, 000, 127, MAYON ST, , , QUEZON CITY, , 000, 033, 00003, , , , , A, C, R, 0]**

```
        for (String element: values){
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpTin", element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpClsfCode",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpRegisteredName",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpLname",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpFname",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpMname",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaBranchCode",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaSubstreet",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaStreet",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaBarangay",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaDistrict",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaCity",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaZipCode",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tplBranchCode",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tplRdoCode",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tplMunCode",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tplContactLname",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tplContactFname",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tplContactMname",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tplContactTelno",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpStatus",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaStatusCode",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("tpaRegisterFlag",  element);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("oTin",  element);

            System.out.println("test " + element);


        }
        System.out.println("The list2: " +jsonObjectReturn);
```

the output of test is **test 118708139
test I

test 

test LABRAMONTE

test JESUS

test CALUMPIANO

test 000

test 127

test MAYON ST

test 

test 

test QUEZON CITY

test 

test 000

test 033

test 00003

test 

test 

test 

test 

test A

test C

test R

test 0**

and the ouput of list2 is **The list2: {"tpaDistrict":"0","tpaBranchCode":"0","tpaStreet":"0","tpaRegisterFlag":"0","tpaStatusCode":"0","tplContactFname":"0","tpClsfCode":"0","oTin":"0","tpFname":"0","tpaCity":"0","tplRdoCode":"0","tpaBarangay":"0","tpTin":"0","tplContactMname":"0","tpRegisteredName":"0","tpMname":"0","tpaZipCode":"0","tplBranchCode":"0","tpStatus":"0","tpaSubstreet":"0","tplContactTelno":"0","tplMunCode":"0","tplContactLname":"0","tpLname":"0"}**

now, what I want to happen is to put the values of "test" inside my jsonObjectReturn. I tried to put it inside the forloop but I can only get "0" as the values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `for..each` loop is the culprit. it actually ends up setting the **LAST ELEMENT** of your JSON (which is zero) to all your `jsonObjectReturn` keys

since the order is pre-determined (I figured since you are using a `LinkedList`), just use that  to set the `jsonObjectReturn` values:

```
jsonObjectReturn.put("tpTin", values[0]);
jsonObjectReturn.put("tpClsfCode", values[1]);
// and so on..
```